# Elasticsearch failed to install multiple plugins in one command

Tags: elasticsearch

As stated in documentation, plugins can be installed through the following command:

```
$ sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu
```

However, when installing with more than one plugins, the system prompted the followings

```
 $ sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu repository-s3
 ERROR: Found multiple arguments for option [arguments], but you asked for only one
```

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/docs/plugins/plugin-script.asciidoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the latest version ES 7.5.2, you can only install one plugin at a time.

The ability to install multiple plugins at once has been added very recently and will only be available from [ES 7.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/7.6/installing-multiple-plugins.html) onwards, which has not yet been released. 7.6 should be coming out anytime now since there are only 2 issues and 4 PRs left open. Stay tuned...